# Git server for large number of heavy files

Tags: git

We are looking for an alternative git backend, in fact we are intending to setup a git with a large file number and each file could be heavy in size. The project is under specification, but the files whose we want the revision are mostly bundled files (proprietary technologie). I'm not sure but talking about for the start of the project about 100 000 files, with 10Mo of file.

I have read that it could be possible but, not found any production ready solution.

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you please give specific numbers? For instance "It must support 1 million files of 10 gigabytes each" or something similar. Thanks!

Comment: Talking about "big files", did you think about something like [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/)?

Comment: The project is under specification, but the files whose we want the revision are mostly bundled files (proprietary technologie). I'm not sure but talking about for the start of the project about 100 000 files, with 10Mo of file. git-annex is a good start :) thanks !

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and let us know if it fits. You could even [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then.